# Вывод времени в привычном формате. Задача

Tags: php, логика

Интересует пример реализации данной задачи на php

Электронные часы в кабинете информатики после выпуска обновлений стали показывать время необычным способом. 
Теперь они показывают угол поворота часовой стрелки (x) от начального значения в полночь.

Напишите программу, которая сможет выводить привычное время в формате часов и минут. 
Например, 90 = 3 часа и 0 минут.

Формат ввода
90

Формат вывода
3 0

Буду благодарен за новодки

Comment: Смотрите, круг имеет 360 градусов. Я попробовал сложить пропорцию и понял, что на 36 градусов будет 12 часов. Перевёл 12 часов в минуты и получилось, что на 360 градусов есть 720 минут. Тоесть градус будем множить на 2. Потом эти минуты мы будем переводить в часы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так. Я не приспосабливал код к выводу секунд.

```
$d = 90; // Наш градус

$hours = floor($d * 2 / 60); // Закруглим к меньшему
$mins = $d * 2 - $hours * 60;

echo $hours . ' ' . $mins;
```

*Живой пример:*

```js
var d = prompt();

var hours = Math.floor(d * 2 / 60);
var mins  = Math.floor(d * 2 - hours * 60);
var secs  = Math.round(d * 2 - hours * 60 - mins);

console.log(hours + ' ' + mins + ' ' + secs);
```

Comment: вот это бы на php было бы вообще идеально!

Comment: @Денис, обновил

Comment: Зачем `* 2 / 60` если можно сразу разделить на 30?

Comment: @Эникейщик, да первое, что в голову пришло.. Легче для понимания